# Python sys.argv command line troubles for someone new to python

Tags: python, command-line

I'm new to learning python and been having trouble understanding what `sys.argv` is and how it is used for command line arguments in python. I have tested with it, played around with it, watched tutorials but they always skip the basic thing that I don't understand!

How do I utilize it on windows from the most basic level and what is it used for?

Secondly, I can show an example of some notes from a class that includes codes provided:

CLASS NOTES START

• Copy a text file, but adding line numbers:
 file names given as command line args
e.g. script invoked as:
python add line nums.py foo.txt foo copy.txt

```
import sys
infile = open(sys.argv[1],’r’) # open input file
outfile = open(sys.argv[2],’w’) # open output file
num=0
for line in infile: # read input file stream, line by line
num = num+1
print >> outfile, num, line, # write to out-stream
infile.close() # close input stream
outfile.close() # close output stream
```

CLASS NOTES END

It would be great if you could explain on the basic level from scratch how `sys.argv` is used and how to use it on command line and what the class notes above means following your explanation.

Comment: Have you used a command line before, and do you know what command-line arguments are?

Comment: "how do I utilize it on windows" -- are you aware of the command prompt on windows, or are you coming at this from the perspective of someone who has never used a command line program on Windows?

Comment: i have used command line and I know how to do "cd ____" etc to go through directories but I just don't understand what that class note is teaching and what the basics of using sys.argv is :(

Answer (score 1):

`sys.argv` is a python list of all the command line arguments passed to your python program.

To find out what you can use it for, try writing a simple python script:

```
import sys    
for arg in sys.argv:
    print(arg)
```

Then try running this on the command line and looking at what it outputs.

```
$ python my.py arg1 arg2 arg3
```

This works in both linux and windows in the same way.

To answer your "what is it used for?" question - it can be used to pass options or configuration to a program. Most often it's used to pass input filenames to a python script (as your example shows)

Comment: thank you for your answer, it helped some, but now im still having trouble understanding the example, could you go through what it does please?

Comment: Have you tried running the example? I'm not sure any explanation will help better than actually trying things out and trying to think it through.  You're obviously taking a course in the subject - so I suggest you do some reading on python [lists](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_lists.htm), [for loops](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_loops.htm) and [IO](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_files_io.htm)

Comment: Yeah if i put your example code in a file, e.g. my file being called "Cmd.py", i run it on command line by using the standard "python Cmd.py" but i put some arguments next to it it prints those arguments out when i hit enter. Like "python Cmd.py 1 2 3" prints Cmd.py 1 2 3 on separate lines. Does this mean with sys.argv i can type something in command line like a file and it will go through my code and whatever my code is it might interact with what i typed in?